# Corresponding author in Philosophy

Tags: philosophy

Who is the corresponding author in a field like Philosophy where there is no experimental work to be done and where sometimes the two authors are all senior philosophers?

Comment: I don't mean this to be flippant or unhelpful, but: who cares?  Nowadays, any academic with a solid web-presence is easy to contact.  If all authors have stable email addresses, they can all be contacted about their work....and they should be.

Comment: Do you mean this in the context of who gets assigned the most prestigious position in author ordering, or something else? Some fields assign a lot of prestige to the Corresponding Author, and many just use it as a tag for the author that supposed to answer questions from the readership. Can you clarify which one you care about?

Comment: There is a grant I want to apply for and they request that I mention the corresponding author of my jointly authored papers. That's why I care about it. They have not responded to my query and this is why I am asking it here.

Comment: Is this case where 1) you have several papers already published 
2) you are applying for a grant where they are asking who was the 'corresponding' author for those papers you are listing to support the grant?  In my naive interpretation, wouldn't corresponding author already be in place? (who was the one who did the 'corresponding' with the journal?)